# How to use GHC’s `ReadPrec`?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The [documentation for `GHC.Read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/GHC-Read.html) describes `readPrec` only by:

> Proposed replacement for readsPrec using new-style parsers (GHC only).

Other functions, types, etc. have no documentation at all. How do I use the supposedly more efficient parsing functionality in the intended way? Why is it more efficient?

---

The toy example I’d like to try out the new GHC approach is this:

```hs
data RoseTree a = RoseTree a [RoseTree a] deriving (Eq)

-- | A RoseTree is being displayed "label[children…]" for
-- | nonempty children and just "label" for a leaf (= tree with no children).
instance Show a => Show (RoseTree a) where
    show (RoseTree label []) = show label
    show (RoseTree label ts) = show label ++ show ts

-- | Parses outputs of `show` to a RoseTree.
instance Read a => Read (RoseTree a) where
    readsPrec n str = do
        (label, labelRemaining) <- readsPrec n str
        let tsReads = readsPrec n labelRemaining
        (ts, tsRemaining) <- ([], labelRemaining) : tsReads
        return (RoseTree label ts, tsRemaining)
```

I wrote this several years back for my Bachelor’s thesis and to be honest, I don’t understand the `Read` instance anymore. The code includes the `Show` instance as `Read` morally requires `Show` and should be compatible with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? It's intended for implementing `Read` instances, which the default derived ones will do; If you `derive Read` it'll use the 'more efficient' version already. You only really need to worry about `readPrec` if you are implementing your own `Read` instances, which you _probably_ shouldn't as `Show/Read` aren't really meant for general serialisation.

Comment: I want to implement a `Read` instance for a custom type (where it makes sense). My code isn’t production code but more or less toy code, my goal is to learn something. However, the generated `Show` and `Read` instances truly aren’t great for my type and I have a working implementation for the old style. I’m just curious about the new stuff.

Comment: @Bolpat: It might help if you show a (toy) type with the expected `Read`, then likely we can help you more effective.

Comment: Rather than define a custom `Show` instance, just derive `Show` and `Read` and define your own rosetree-to-string method for display purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadPrec` is (slightly) further documented in [Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadPrec.html). It implements the usual parser classes (`Applicative`, `Monad`, `Alternative`), so you should be able to use it something like this:

```
instance Read a => Read (RoseTree a) where
    -- a instance              vvvvvvvv
    readPrec = liftA2 RoseTree readPrec (readPrec <|> pure [])
    -- [RoseTree a] instance             ^^^^^^^^
    readListPrec = readListPrecDefault
```

You may want to think how this should interact with precedence, then insert appropriate calls to `step` and `prec`. You might also choose to use `<++` over `<|>`; the former is generally more efficient but may commit to its first argument too soon and prevent certain things from parsing that otherwise ought to.